# error log handeling to custom file

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to log all error's that are generated whit error_reporting(E_ALL); in a logfile.
Thus the error's you normaly see when there is an error in the PHP script.
I tried many thing but the closest that i come was whit

```
asdasc();  // generate error
$i=error_get_last();
if($i['message']!==''){
error_log(date('Y-m-d-h:m:s') . " | type = " .$i ['type']." message = " .$i ['message']." file = " .$i ['file']." line = " .$i ['line'] , 3, "my-errors.log");}
```

This way i see that there was an error at a date,but what i want to see is what error i should see if it was on mine screen. something like :
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)    OR
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function blabla() in C:\xampp\htdocs...\index.php on line 125

Is there a way to do this?

thnx in advanced.

Comment: Yes! Process the Database access extension errors in your code. Show some example database access code, and tell us which database access extension you are using

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply , but i realy don't need it for only the databaseconnection errors (if I'm understanding you properly) but all the errors, I've eddited mine question. so also error's like undefined function.

Comment: The best error handling code you can write is none. Seriously. Just let the app crash normally and tweak the [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) directive to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `error_get_last()`:

```
error_log(date('Y-m-d-h:m:s') . " | error = " . print_r(error_get_last(), true), 3, "my-errors.log");
```

You can as well set up your own error handling class in your application:

```
class MyErrorHandlerClass
{
    public function MyErrorHandlerMethod($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars)
    {
        // log you error
    }
}
```

Then you can define your own error handler:

```
$ErrorHandler = new MyErrorHandlerClass();
set_error_handler(array($ErrorHandler, 'MyErrorHandlerMethod'));
```

`error_reporting()` btw. does not generate errors, it only controls the level of displaying errors. When an error occurs, its stack trace is always generated.

Comment: good thinking but unfortanaly the only thing i get in the log file is:
    2015-12-02-09:12:22 | error =

Comment: Calling your undefined function will result in a fatal error. To handle this, you can use `register_shutdown_function()` as described in this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php#92810)